# Problems when plotting the HDI confidence in pirateplot

Tags: r, jags

I'm using the pirateplot (yarrr package) in R to explore some data. But when I try to use a HDI confidence interval, I got the error:

Error: object 'dens.x.i' not found

I do not have any variable with the name dens.x.i and I do not know where it would came from. The command I've used is that:

---

> pirateplot(formula = Kappa ~ Technique,
>   +            data = drri,
>   +            theme.o = 2,
>   +            pal = "lubitel",
>   +            point.pch = 16,
>   +            main = "Kappa",
>   +            ylim=c(0,1.2),
>   +            line.lwd = 3,
>   +            point.cex = 1,
>   +            jitter.val = .01,
>   +            line.o = 0.7,
>   +            bar.o = 0.5,
>   +            point.o = 0.9,
>   +            hdi.o = 0.75,
>   +            back.col = gray(.98))

Error: object 'dens.x.i' not found

---

Anyone can help me?

Comment: It's probably a constructed object 'under the hood', though with some minimal dput data it would be easier to say.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. What did you mean by dput?

Comment: it is often used in conjunction with head to share a minimal or sufficient amount of exemplary data that the code that you've tried, which you included, can be assessed against.  >dput(head(your_object, n = 20)) at your console would return structure(list(subject & etc of your drri object. You copy all of that and paste it here by edit with 4 space indent on each line to look pretty and people have both your data and what you tried to play with. As the error refers to dense, which probably means density as an optional method of evaltuation in HDI, it wasn't found and yarrr can't plot it. data?

Comment: Hi Chris. You are right: I used a larger set of data and the hdi worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: Great! Now, as a matter of helping others, dput(head(drri, n = ? -> the minimum amount to get a valid HDI)) and edit your question to add the dput data. Then answer your question and accept your own answer and everyone will come away with better information and you'll come away with a reputation >1.  And this question won't linger as an unanswered question. Consider, you came here once for clarification. You'll probably be back... Muito prazer!